# The magnitude of the normal force on an inclined plane in two different coordinate systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vectors

After years of solving this problem over and over again as a tutor, this is the first time I came across this question. Solving this could be useful if a future student asks this.

Let's say there's a block on an inclined plane of mass $m$, we have the following two coordinate system in which we can represent the forces on the block:
[image: Vertical and horizontal axes coordinate system]

[image: Inclined coordinate system]

As you can see, we have two different expressions for the magnitude of the normal force. I don't know how to justify this because if we assume each coordinate system is orthonormal, then one would be just the rotation of the other and the magnitude of the normal should be the same in both of the coordinate systems. Obviously I'm missing something or something is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: @Bhavay: good find. Voted to close as 'duplicate'.

Comment: It does, I'm very glad to have a new way of seeing this old classic, thank you!

Comment: Actually this question is all wrong, if the block is sliding there should be a y-component for the acceleration

Comment: Yes. And if it is not sliding, a friction force should be considered, and it also changes with coordinate system.